# Jquery-Mobile: How to reload/refresh the internal page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages(i.e., page_1 and page_2) in the container page(i.e., page.html).In the first page i have only one button if you click on that then it will navigates to the second page.when you come back from the second page to First page and once again click on the button for navigating to the second page at this time i want to reload/refresh the page. i tried but i am not getting please can anybody help me.

Here the code:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="page_1" >    

        <div data-role="content" id="contentlogin">         
            <a href="#"  onclick="refresh();" data-role="button" id="login">Navigation</a>                          
        </div>             
    </div> 

   <div data-role="page" id="page_2" >    

        <div data-role="content" id="contentlogin">         
            //Some Form elements are there      
        </div>             
    </div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 function refresh()
 {                                            
           $.mobile.changePage($("#page_2"), {transition: "pop",reloadPage: true});
 }    
</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/sJdfy/4/

JS

```
$('#page_3').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    // refresh specific element
    $('#refresh').val('');
});

$('#page_2').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    // refresh all elements
    var allInputs = $(':input');
    allInputs.val('');
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_1" >    
    <div data-role="content" name="contentlogin">         
        <a href="#page_2" data-role="button" id="login">Navigate to page 2</a>   
        <a href="#page_3" data-role="button">Navigate to page 3</a>     
        Yeah Page 1        
    </div>             
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="page_2" >
    <div data-role="content" name="contentlogin">
        <a href="#page_1" data-role="button">Navigate to page 1</a>     
        <!-- Some Form elements are there -->
        Hello we are on Page 2<br />Refresh All Elements<br /><br />
        <label for="basic1">Text Input 1 (Refresh):</label>
        <input type="text" name="name1" id="basic1" value="" />   
        <label for="refresh1">Text Input 2 (Refresh):</label>
        <input type="text" name="name21" id="refresh1" value="" />
        <br /> Enter in some values, Navigate to Page 1 and back to Page 2    
    </div>             
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="page_3" >
    <div data-role="content" name="contentlogin">
        <a href="#page_1" data-role="button">Navigate to page 1</a>     
        <!-- Some Form elements are there -->
        Hello we are on Page 3<br />Refresh Specific Elements<br /><br />
        <label for="basic">Text Input 1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value="" />   
        <label for="refresh">Text Input 2 (Refresh):</label>
        <input type="text" name="name2" id="refresh" value="" />
        <br /> Enter in some values, Navigate to Page 1 and back to Page 3
    </div>             
</div>
```